# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tart_time\n2008-05-06 04:41:2'

Tags: python-2.7

I have a timestamp in the form `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` . I want to use the month part, so I wrote the code below.

I tried to use `int(float(date)[4:-2])` instead and it didn't work

```
def findWeather(date):

   weather = ""

   month = int(str(date)[4:-2])
```

Comment: Try to print `str(date)[4:-2]` to debug. Apparently it's not a valid base 10 number.

Comment: The slice `[4:-2]`, applied to the format you claim your timestamp is in, would be `-MM-DD HH:MM:` - hardly something you could turn into an integer.  And that's not the actual format of the data anyway, as evidenced by the "tart_time\n" part in the error message.